# jQuery datatables - how to set the column name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, datatables

I have a jQuery datable pluged into my ASP.NET application and currently, in order to show the column names, I have the following piece of code in my Razor view..

```
<table id="myDataTable" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Contact name</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Project</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="font-size:x-small"></tbody>
</table>
```

Then, I have my javascript for the jQuery datatbles...

```
$('#myDataTable').DataTable({
        "bServerSide": false,
        "sAjaxSource": //controller binding,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sName": "CONTACT_NAME" },
            { "sName": "TITLE"},
            { "sName": "COUNTRY" },
            { "sName": "CITY" },
            { "sName": "PROJECT" },
        ],
        "bDestroy":true
    });
```

However, when I render the HTML the first time before I fill in the table, it looks awkward because I am rending some random HTML (that is related to the future column names) with no datatable at all...

How can I define the column of my table without having to set it in the HTML so I can avoid having that random text there?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about a flash of unstyled content? Try starting with the html part hidden.

Comment: Hi, no flash in here. Basically I just have a HTML that will render the column names once I enhance with the jQuery datatables but before I enhance with the datatables I want it to be hidden. If I try to use the HTML hidden attribute, then it will be always hidden as I don't know a way to distinguish when I've called the datatables. Not sure if my explanation makes sense though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set the initial CSS of the `#myDataTable` to `visibility:hidden;` like this:

```
#myDataTable { visibility:hidden; }
```

That way you can put it right in the HTML and just call the following JavaScript to show it after you update the values:

```
document.getElementById('#myDataTable').style.visibility = "visible";
```

Comment: Nice! It did the trick! However, I had to set it like this...

`document.getElementById('myDataTable').style.visibility = "visible";`

Comment: arf  ... right... hashtag on the brain, sorry  ;)  (glad it worked out for you)